# woocommerce product hide by custom fields in shop page

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I tried using this function

> woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item

but its not working i want to filter products using custom field data with function.php

I want to filter the products on shop page with custom field data

Comment: What did you try adding to `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item`?

Comment: which function i can use for acheive that result